# Linking products to categories

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, link-category

I want my WooCommerce products to be linked to proper categories. I already have categories and products. These needs to shuffle to the new linking.

Please suggest the detail steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using csv product import plugins like https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-xml-csv-product-import/ .
The best way is to write a custom script as per your requirements.